# How do I modify this program to make use of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

First of all, here are the instructions:
http://ideone.com/eRHwUo
Yes, this is homework! With that being said (and because I simply love the language), when you do post answers, **please try to use pseudo code so that I just don't copy and paste** into my program. Thank you!

As far as the code goes, I've done everything needed in for the section where the user enters all of the input. **However, I need help with 'transferring' the data from the classes to the 'ArrayList' that we're supposed to use.** I figure that once I get that down, I'll be able to just sort through the array to find the ID number for selection "B", and if the user enters "C" I'll just cycle through the array displaying everything in it.

Anyway, onto the code (this is main):

```
/*
 * Name:
 * Date:
 * Assignment 2
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class homework 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char userSelection;
        String convertString;
        String userStrings;
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        do 
        {
            System.out.println("Here are your choices:");
            System.out.println("A. Enter employee data" +
                             "\nB. Search for employee data" +
                             "\nC. List all data" +
                             "\nD. Exit");

            convertString = kbd.next();
            userSelection = convertString.charAt(0);

            switch(userSelection)
            {
            case 'A':
                GetUserInfo();
                break;
            case 'B':
                // Stuff;
                break;
            case 'C':
                // Display all data;
                break;
            case 'D':
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Error, that is not a valid entry. Please try again.");
            }
        } while (userSelection > 'D');
    }

    // Write functions here
    public static void GetUserInfo()
    {
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String empID;
        double hourlyRate;
        int hoursWorked;
        double withPercent;

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is your first name?");
        firstName = kbd.next();

        System.out.println("What is your last name?");
        lastName = kbd.next();

        System.out.println("What is your employee ID?");
        empID = kbd.next();

        Employee user = new Employee(empID);

        user.setFirstName(firstName);
        user.setLastName(lastName);

        System.out.println("What is your hourly rate?");
        hourlyRate = kbd.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("How many hours did you work?");
        hoursWorked = kbd.nextInt();

        System.out.println("What is your withholding percentage?");
        withPercent = kbd.nextDouble();

        Pay user1 = new Pay();

        user1.setHourlyRate(hourlyRate);
        user1.setHoursWorked(hoursWorked);
        user1.setWithPercent(withPercent);
    }
}
```

This is the Employee class:

```
public class Employee 
{
    // Members of the class
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String employeeID;
    // remember about the pay object

    // EmployeeID constructor
    public Employee(String empID)
    {
        this.employeeID = empID;
    }

    // Below are the various getters and setters of the Employee class
    public String getFirstName() 
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) 
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() 
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) 
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmployeeID() 
    {
        return employeeID;
    }

}
```

And this is the Pay class:

```
public class Pay 
{
    // Members of the class
    double hourlyRate;
    int hoursWorked;
    double withPercent;

    // Various getters and setters of the Pay class
    public double getHourlyRate() 
    {
        return hourlyRate;
    }

    public void setHourlyRate(double hourlyRate)
    {
        this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
    }

    public int getHoursWorked() 
    {
        return hoursWorked;
    }

    public void setHoursWorked(int hoursWorked) 
    {
        this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    }

    public double getWithPercent() 
    {
        return withPercent;
    }

    public void setWithPercent(double withPercent)
    {
        this.withPercent = withPercent;
    }   

    // Calculates the raw payment
    public double CalcPayRate(double hourlyRate, int hoursWorked)
    {
        return hourlyRate * hoursWorked;
    }

    // If the employee has worked overtime, calculates the new payment
    public double CalcOvertimePay(double hourlyRate, int hoursWorked)
    {
        double rawPay = 0;

        rawPay = hourlyRate * hoursWorked;

        if (hoursWorked > 40)
        {
            rawPay *= 1.5;
        }

        return rawPay;
    }

    // Calculates final amount that the employee will be paid
    public double CalcTotalPay(double hourlyRate, int hoursWorked, double withPercent)
    {
        double rawPay = 0;
        double subTotalPay = 0;
        double finalPay = 0;

        rawPay = hourlyRate * hoursWorked;
        subTotalPay = rawPay * withPercent;
        finalPay = rawPay - subTotalPay;

        return finalPay;
    }
}
```

So, thoughts please?
Also, final comments:
(1) I don't understand what 'Pay Object' is supposed to do under the Employee class?
(2) How do I use the input data to create a 'Pay Object' and then create an employee object?
Those are the two parts from the instructions I'm a little unclear about, and as such if you could shade some light on that, it'd be helpful!
(3) If there's anything that seems off about my syntax, please let me know about it so I can change it accordingly. I'm still new to this language, so any help would be great.

Edit: I have updated my code with comments:

```
public class homework 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        do 
        {
            // Stuff commented out for readability

            case 'A':
                PromptForInput();
                // Employee emp = PromptForInput();
                // employeeList.add(emp);
                break;
            } while (userSelection > 'D');
    }

    // public static Employee PromptInput()
    public static void PromptForInput()
    {           
        Employee user = new Employee(empID);

        // Isn't this supposed to be returned as well?          
        Pay user1 = new Pay();

        user1.setHourlyRate(hourlyRate);
        user1.setHoursWorked(hoursWorked);
        user1.setWithPercent(withPercent);

        //return user;
    }
}
```

Is that how it's supposed to look?
I still do not understand the 'pay object' part of the assignment..

Comment: FYI: Whitespace doesn't mean plain text. [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)) is actually a programming language.

Comment: +1 for wanting to learn, asking for direction and not wanting a copy and paste solution.  So refreshing!

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm inclined to want to -1 for wall of code (not that I will).

Comment: @Dukeling At least it shows effort ;)

Comment: Seems like you have to hard code values of each `Pay` object, and then store/provide information as needed from that object. You can ask for this information inside the constructor of the `Employee` Class (for simple purpose) and then create an object of `Pay` likewise based on those values. Now each Object of `Employee` is associated with a single `Pay` Object, now add `Employee` object inside an `ArrayList` inside the `Homework Class`. __H__ should be capital (Pascal case applies to class Names) :-)

Comment: You should always do user input validation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

If I was doing this...

I would return the `Employee` from the `getUserInfo` method and add it to the `ArrayList` within the calling method.  This keeps the `getUserInfo` method focused on a single responsibility.

I would also allow the `getUserInfo` to return `null` if the values entered by the user did not pass validation, but this might be beyond the scope of the requirements.

For example...

```
List<Employee> employees = // create ArrayList...
//...

Employee emp = getUserInfo();
if (emp != null) {
    employees.add(emp);
}
```

You should also setting a `Pay` object to the `Employee` when you create it, this will associate the `Pay` object to the `Employee` so you can find it later

As to your `Pay` object.  The `CalcPayRate`, `CalcOvertimePay` and `CalcTotalPay` don't required parameters, as all the information required for these methods should be available from the properties of the object...

For example...

```
public double getRawPay() {
    return getHoursWorked() & getHourlyRate();
}
```

I would also encourage you to take a look at [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

**Updated #1**

Associating the `Pay` object with the `Employee` is no different from how you assiciated things like the employee's names

Basically, you need to supply a instance field/property to hold the reference and some means to set and get the reference, for example...

```
public class Employee 
{
    //...
    Pay pay;

    // EmployeeID constructor
    public Employee(String empID)
    {
        this.employeeID = empID;
    }

    // EmployeeID constructor
    public Employee(String empID, Pay pay)
    {
        this(empID);
        this.pay = pay;
    }

    public void setPay(Pay pay) {
        this.pay = pay;
    }

    public Pay getPay() {
        return pay
    }
    //...
}
```

I've supplied a second constructor, you don't really need it, but it's a demonstration of how it might be achieved.

Then you would simply pass the reference of `Pay` to `Employee`...

```
Employee emp = new Employee(...);
//...
Pay pay = new Pay();
//...
emp.setPay(pay);
```

**Update #2**

Another approach would be to create an instance of Pay when Employee is created...

```
public class Employee 
{
    //...
    Pay pay = new Pay();

    // EmployeeID constructor
    public Employee(String empID)
    {
        this.employeeID = empID;
    }
```

This would suggest we no longer need `setPay`, but that's up to you.

When you need to get or set values for Pay, you simple ask the instance of Employee for it

```
Employee emp = ...;
emp.getPay().setHourlyRate(hourlyRate);
//...
double hourlyRate = emp.getPay().getHourlyRate();
```

**Updated #3**

Basically, you need to associate an instance of `Pay` with an instance of `Employee`.  If it makes it easier, name it something else...

Based on the example from Update #1

```
public static Employee PromptForInput()
{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String empID;
    double hourlyRate;
    int hoursWorked;
    double withPercent;

    //...
    Employee user = new Employee(empID);

    user.setFirstName(firstName);
    user.setLastName(lastName);

    //...

    Pay payObj = new Pay();

    payObj .setHourlyRate(hourlyRate);
    payObj .setHoursWorked(hoursWorked);
    payObj .setWithPercent(withPercent);

    // Don't forget to give an instance of Pay to the instance
    // of Employee
    user.setPay(payObj);

    return user;
}
```

Think of `Employee` as a container, it contains the name and ID of the employee as well as their pay details.  When you start with a new instance of `Employee`, it is just an empty container, you need to fill it...

When you need to, you simply request and instance of `Pay` from the `Employee` via the `getPay`

**Update #4**

Based on you new code, I would only make one small suggestion...

In your display all data choice, you could use the following loop to display the Employee AND the Employee's pay rate, for example...

```
for (int i = 0; i < employeeList.size(); i++)
{
    Employee emp = employeeList.get(i);
    System.out.println(emp);
    System.out.println(emp.getPay().CalcPayRate());
}
```

Comment: I was about to add a comment about the code convention. +1 for mentioning that. +1 for well prepared answer. I m sorry that `1+1=1` in SO :P

Comment: Thank you. But then what is the Pay class used for? How would I get the values from that class to the pay object inside of the Employee class? I'm more lost than before.. this is my main(): http://ideone.com/jaJxDu and this is the Employee class: http://ideone.com/ArLDq8

Comment: You would get the values for the Pay or tithe same way you get the values from Employee object.  emp.getPay().getHoursWorked(); for example. Or you can ask for the instance of Pay from Employee and assign back to some other variable, Pay pay = emp.getPay();

Comment: Ins't that exactly what I'm doing in the last few lines of main()? http://ideone.com/jaJxDu

Comment: I don't see where your associating the pay object with the instance of Employee...

Comment: Also, be careful with the Employee(Pay) constructor, you've ignored the employeeID

Comment: Once you leave the promptForInput method, any reference to Pay is lost, you can't recover it, unless you first give it to the employee instance. This way, when you retrieve a instance of Employee from the List, you can ask for an associated Pay instance. This allows for distance management of the data where it's required.

Comment: http://ideone.com/b4s3in - if I try to use 'user' with user.SetHourlyRate(), etc I get an error saying "The method is undefined for the type Employee"

Comment: That's because it's a method of Pay, there are different objects. You need to either create a new instance of Pay when Employee is created or as my example shows, supply an instance to it. When you want to work on Pay, you need to get that instance from Employee via the getPay method....

Comment: I'm still completely lost. I think a huge point of confusion for me is the fact that there's a `pay`class and a `pay` object being named exactly the same thing.

Comment: The Pay class is a contract, it states what can be give to and gotten from an instance of Pay. pay (the variable/reference/instance) allows you to interact with it, but allows y create many stance of Pay, all with their own values.  Think of it as a Car. A Car is a Class/Object, it has an engine, wheels, doors and seats. A Porsche 911 is an instance of Car, it defines the properties of this instance of Car (like color for example), but it's still a Car...confused yet ;)

Comment: I just saw your edit. I really, really appreciate that you're trying to help me, but I simply do not understand what's going on. On top of not knowing where anything should be at this point, I don't know what where this should go: `Pay pay = new Pay();`. Towards the end of the `PromptForInput()` method? Inside the Employee class? And I still don't know how I'd even get the hours/pay information inside of the same Employee ArrayList. What's worse is that I'm frustrated to no end, there's nothing regarding ArrayLists in my book, and my professor hasn't covered it yet.

Comment: Again, thank you for keeping up with me. To 'unfrustrate' myself I was working on other parts of this assignment to get it as close to finished as possible. Back to your 3rd update, though - I understood all of that. What I don't understand is how 'user' gains access to the members of the `Pay Class`.

Comment: This is my code updated code: `main()`:http://ideone.com/ljh7pV `Employee`:http://ideone.com/saiRbx `Pay`:http://ideone.com/e1gq3R. Where, exactly, am I going wrong?

Comment: user gets access to an instance of Pay via its pay variable as presented in my first and third updates. Also if Pay and pay are confusing, call the instance something else, like wage for example. This is where you the naming conventions are so important, because when I look at the code, I automatically see the difference between a Class and variable ;)

Comment: That's coming along really well! You have all the basics in place!

Comment: Oh my god I finally figured it out. Thank you so much for that! The naming is what really threw me off. I have one last question as it's my last bug - for part "B", I need to input an ID number and then how do I test it against all the strings inside of the employeeList (the ListArray) in order to find it? I'm confused because I can't run a string or an int against the ListArray because the string/int aren't of the same class (employee). I can post my current updated code if you wish to see what I mean

Comment: Take the loop from your "display all" option. Instead of dumping every result, compare the Employee's ID from the list with the value you have, remember, use String#equals to String comparisons. If they match, display the Employee..

Comment: Normally to compare something within an array, I'd do something like this: http://ideone.com/pPD0c4 but, clearly, the 'if' statement is wrong. Edit: the compiler says the following: Incompatible operand types String and Employee

Comment: Needs to be `if (tempVal.equals(employeeList.get(i)))`

Comment: In reply to your update #4: I currently have this in the `Employee Class` at the bottom: http://ideone.com/6gUbeL

Comment: (1) I've come across another problem.. sigh. Assuming I have input the data of 4+ users, I go to option 'B' to input the ID and check if it's stored. If it is, how do I make sure the loop only displays that employee's data and no one else's? and (2) I want to have the loop in option 'C' inside of a method, and have main call that method from inside 'C'. However, when I do that, I get an error saying that `size()` and `get()` are not defined. How do I fix that?

Comment: 1- The comparison is case sensitive 2- Is there anything in the list?

Comment: Yes, I just input the information for 3 employees, and when the check for the ID came up, it would always go to the `"Error, ID number not found.`

Comment: :P, the `if` stament should actually be `if (tempVal.equals(employeeList.get(i).getEmployeeID())) {`...

Comment: (1) Think we might have fixed this...(2) You need to pass the `employeeList` to the method, so it has something to work with, in you method decleration, add a parameter for `ArrayList<Employee>`, all it `employeeList` to keep things simple...`public static void listAll(ArrayList<Employee> employeeList) {...`

Comment: Well, that fixed it! Thank you (yet again :)). One last thing - I want to take the loop out of 'C' and instead have that line call the `DisplayData()` method that has the loop inside of it. How do I pass the `employeeList` as the argument? If I do `public static void DisplayData(Employee employeeList)`, I'll get the error that basically says `size()` and `get()` are not part of the `Employee` class. Thoughts on how to fix that? Edit: Just saw your post (posted seconds after mine)

Comment: OKAY SO, thank you sosososo incredibly much for your enormous amount of help. If it wasn't for you, I don't think I would've been able to finish this without tearing my hair out. Since I can't return the favor, I just want to say, honestly, thank you very much!

Comment: One day, you will have the opportunity to help others, just as others have helped me ;)

Comment: Oh, one last minor thing.. say I input the information for an employee, right? Everything will be fine. Then I'll ask to see that employee's information.. again, everything is fine. But then if I ask to display that information again, the `CalcTotalPay()` amount rises every time I ask for that user's information, but it'll never go over the `CalcPayRate` amount. Thoughts? Here's what I mean.. http://i.imgur.com/a0TfBsk.png (notice the Total Pay amount)

Comment: You've changed something in your `Pay` class because the last code sample I have available doesn't exhibit this issue.

Comment: Nevermind - found it! I added `withPercent = withPercent / 100`, not realizing I was changing the member variable `withPercent` every time. I assigned that calculation to a new variable instead and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments. If you need help with something that's beyond the scope of your question, consider opening a chat room.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the instructions, I think your just supposed to create an ArrayList with a generic type of Employee. The GetUserInfo() should return the Employee object it just created, and this Employee object should be stored into the ArrayList - right after the function call - with its .add() function.

Edit:

My attempt at your bottom three questions.

1) The Pay Object should be referenced with a variable in the Employee Object. You can use create another setter method in the Employee Object to do this.

2) I believe you already did this by the following code:

```
user1.setHourlyRate(hourlyRate);
user1.setHoursWorked(hoursWorked);
user1.setWithPercent(withPercent);
```

3) The syntax looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

**A. Enter Employee Data**

You are utilizing a class (noun) to perform actions. Actions generally translate to method calls. Even your usage of 'get' (by [convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) classes should not start with get) suggests introducing a method. So, change GetUserInfo to

```
private static Employee promptForEmployeeInfo()

//or more simply
private static Employee getEmployee()
```

Then you can return an employee object after all the necessary information is gathered, including the pay information. Then you will need to provide the pay information to the employee object. In the most basic form, this will be accomplished by instantiating a Pay object and passing it into the constructor of Employee (for immutable objects which is more advanced techniques than you require) or via a setter method.

Inside your main method, the List will be instantiated before your do/while loop. Every time the user enters 'A' you call employeeList.add('insert Employee method call here').

> (1) I don't understand what 'Pay Object' is supposed to do under the Employee class

In object oriented programming (OOP), encapsulating data and actions on that data into a descriptive, appropriately named class is part of OOP convention.

Comment: I wish I could reply to the other 2 answers on here, so I can't so I'll reply here instead. I understand returning an employee object to the GetUserInfo() method. However, if I do something like `return emp` to that method, how am I supposed to also return the hourly rate and hours worked? And I still do not understand what the `pay object` is supposed to do inside the `employee class` ie how it's supposed to look.

Comment: @relapsn After you have created both the Employee and Pay objects, you need to pass the Pay object to the Employee object via the setPay method, there by associating the Pay object with the Employee object

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I really don't understand how I'm to do that. Could you explain it to me, please?

Comment: Yes, you have set the `Pay` related values inside the `Employee` object. But MadProgammer's example takes advantage of OOP and encapsulation to set all three values at one time (1 method call instead of 3). It's just a cleaner more advanced style of coding. You'll eventually learn about it.